# UserAccount matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

When I open article I have this error

> UserAccount matching query does not exist

**views.py**

```
class ArticleDetailView(DetailView, CategoryAndArticleListMixin):

    model = Article
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):

        context = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['article'] = self.get_object()
        context['article_comments'] = self.get_object().comments.all()
        context['form'] = CommentForm
        context['current_user'] = UserAccount.objects.get(user=self.request.user) #probably where the error arises
        return context
```

My UserAccount model

**models.py**

```
class UserAccount(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    favorite_articles = models.ManyToManyField(Article)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('account_user', kwargs={'user': self.user.username})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='base_view'),
    url(r'category/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category-detail'),
    url(r'account_user/(?P<user>[-\w]+)/$', UserAccountView.as_view(), name='account_user'),
    url(r'(?P<category>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
    url(r'show_article_image/$', DynamicArticleImageView.as_view(), name='article_image'),
    url(r'add_comment/$', CreateCommentView.as_view(), name='add_comment'),
    url(r'display_articles_by_category$', DisplayArticlesByCategoryView.as_view(), name='articles_by_category'),
    url(r'user_reaction$', UserReactionView.as_view(), name='user_reaction'),
    url(r'registration/$', RegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration'),
    url(r'login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),]
```

And html code where I using my logic
**post_detail.html**

```
<p class="add_to_favorites {{ article.slug }}">

        {% if article in current_user.favorite_articles.all %}
        <button class="btn btn-disabled">Добавлено в избранное</button>
        {% else %}
        <a href=""><button class="btn btn-danger">Добавить в избранное</button></a>
        {% endif %}
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: seems like you do not have a UserAccount entry in the database with request.user as the user field

Comment: Check if you have a user logged in as error is probably because of the line `context['current_user'] = UserAccount.objects.get(user=self.request.user)`

Comment: @Sanip this problem only for admin(superuser)

Comment: That means you don't have an entry for the superuser in UserAccount. Even though the superuser exists, an UserAccount entry for that user is missing.